# Default Value in Picklist

Tags: picklist, default-value

on salesforce, I have a picklist type field which contains three values: (1, 2, 3) But the value - None - disturbs all users.

1. I set the value 1 as default when creating but I still have the value -None- appear in the drop-down list of choices. I want to know how to delete the value -None- from the possible values.

The display is as follows:

```
                           -None-
                           1
                           2
                           3
```

And the value 1 is that which is checked, by default I have defined it, but when I try to choose another value, I find the value -None- and I can also choose it, I want that this value which is by default delete it

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete the `--None--` value.

It's an inherent part of how Salesforce presents picklists when editing a record or picklist field. It's a visual representation of `null`, or nothingness.

When you select that value, the picklist has nothing selected. Save the record and the record detail page will have no value shown.

Comment: Can I add a validation rule for example in case the user chooses -None- as a choice to display a blocking message indicating that he must choose one of the three values??
​

Comment: @laila19 Yes, you could make a validation rule for that. I'd be cautious in doing so though, because you would need to update all of the existing records where that picklist is blank and it may interfere with people/code/other automation creating new records for that SObject.

Comment: thank you for your help